# Can SSO users be directed away from Salesforce login page?

Tags: single-sign-on, delegated-authentication

So with SSO you can use [Delegated Authentication](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/171031/4126) so that certain profiles *have* to use SSO and cannot login via login.salesforce.com.

Thats fine.

But if those SSO-only users *do* try and login via login.salesforce.com they get the message "Please check your username and password" which causes confusion - its not that their username and password are wrong, the problem is they are in the wrong place.

Is there any way to detect those situations and direct users to the right place for SSO?

edit: Login Flows don't work for this because they are post-authentication

edit: I looked into 'My Domain' functionality - it lets you have a customised login page using your 'my domain' url BUT if you have SSO enabled it forwards everyone straight to the SSO login. (You can pass ?login querystring to the login page and then it gives you both options but its awkward)

Comment: Out of the box - no. You can develop your own custom login page.

Comment: Put that as an answer and ill tick it : )

Comment: Note that you don't have any control over main login page so unless it is for a site/portal, you cannot do what you looking for. You might want to handle this as training issue.

Comment: @identigral update: I looked at 'my domain' feature but if SSO is enabled it just bounces all visitors straight to SSO

Comment: Tell your users to use custom domain to login instead of generic login. We communicate same with our users.

Comment: @AvijitChakraborty Yes maybe but the basic custom domain login always redirects to SSO before asking the user who they are. If you put ?login on the end of the url it works, but will they remember that?